# How to show recent programmes?

Tags: gnome, history

how to display the recently used programmes (not files, that is implemented)?

- I am looking for:
- a function / script or so to do the job.
- How I would like to have the problem solved is something on those lines: To have a button to just being able to one-click on it, on the desktop.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Well... What is not a program? I guess any list of recently used programs would be incomplete. If you rely on the command-line you can use the shell history.

Comment: Why the Gnome tag? Are you asking about only Gnome programs or did you use that tag because you use Gnome Desktop?

Comment: @ Rolfi Can you please check my updated answer below; If it doesn't work, reply and explain what went wrong  //Regards!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Would this work?

```
get_recently_used(){
 find "${1:-.}" -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %P\n' 2>/dev/null | sort | tail -n "${2:-10}";
}
```

**For those who don't want this to be enabled:**
This should work, (if I'm not wrong?)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-app-usage false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy recent-files-max-age 0
```

Comment: Probably related..(unsure)  (Although this is about how to prevent the file from being created, It's still worth reading, maybe some in the future will find it helpful)   https://askubuntu.com/questions/269858/how-do-i-prevent-the-file-recently-used-xbel-from-being-created

Comment: This is only valid for GTK applications.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, Didn't thought about that. My bad

Comment: No problem, this is certainly useful for many Ubuntu users, for which this solution may get close to what OP asks (which is in fact probably an impossibility anyway). Still I think it is worth the mention.

Comment: @Quasímodo I've updated my answer